# Microsoft Graph returns 422 error on querying Sharepoint subsites

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

My API tries to query the subsites of a site in a huge Microsoft Sharepoint, but the Graph API returns a 422 "The request is unprocessable because it uses too many resources" error.

[image]

The URL I called to achieve this was https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site_id/sites . When using the Graph Explorer, this does return about 8-10 subsites, which are then recursively queryable (using their site id in that same URL). This can go about 5 levels deep and each site has a document library with files. In another Sharepoint, my API is able to do this succesfully, because it is way smaller, I assume.

I've also tried using $top and thus limiting the results per response to 1, but that still gave the same error.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be and if there's a workaround for this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: full response body

```
{
    "error": {
        "code":"notSupported", 
        "message": "The request is unprocessable because it uses too many resources",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-07-13T08:21:45", 
            "request-id":"48de58fe-90b5-4a49-8236-e8b2c981e837",
            "client-request-id":"48de58fe-90b5-4a49-8236-e8b2c981e837"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, would you share the request ID and full response so we can look into this?

Comment: Hi @Diana , thanks for responding. I edited my question with the full response body.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @TanmoySengupta See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After suffering from this issue for a long time, I finally solved this by adding `Prefer: apiversion=2.1` as a header to this specific request.

EDIT:

This does not seem to be needed anymore and can possibly cause issues. It has been removed from the [predefined Postman collection](https://www.postman.com/microsoftgraph/workspace/microsoft-graph/overview), so I would suggest trying out your request using that configuration.

Comment: Hi I am facing this issue but adding that header didn't help, still getting that error. Did you do anything else for it to work?

Comment: I found it by playing around in the Microsoft Graph environment from Postman: https://www.postman.com/microsoftgraph/workspace/microsoft-graph/overview . I didn't change anything else, so your best bet is to probably try out these premade methods without changing too much

Comment: adding Prefer:apiversion=2.1 CAUSED the problem for me. If I remove it, it works fine (but $filter is not supported)

Comment: I see they've updated the Postman collection to not use apiversion=2.1 anymore, so I would indeed assume that this answer has become obsolete